# Command gcloud functions describe throws function not found

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

Command `gcloud functions describe <function_name>`  throws `404` but function is deployed correctly.

I've checked the gcloud profile is pointing at the same region and project of the function. I've also checked through the console and the function is displayed under the correct project.

```bash
# gcloud functions list
NAME          STATE   TRIGGER       REGION       ENVIRONMENT
screenwriter  ACTIVE  HTTP Trigger  us-central1  2nd gen

# gcloud functions describe screenwriter
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.describe) ResponseError: status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function screenwriter in region us-central1 in project personal-xyz does not exist]

# gcloud config list
[compute]
region = us-central1
[core]
account = mypersonal@email.com
project = personal-xyz
```

Comment: Perhaps `gcloud functions describe screenwriter --gen2`? See [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/describe)

Comment: I just tried `gcloud functions describe`'ing a Gen2 function of my own and the command indeed requires `--gen2`. That's pretty nasty. It would be useful if `gcloud functions describe` without the `--gen2` prompted "This command does not describe Gen2 functions. If you need to describe a Gen2 function, please add `--gen2` flag"

Comment: Or the ResposeError message should inform it haven't found a First Gen function, just like is does with the region and project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance with @DazWilkin, I agree that the `--gen2` flag is required. When describing a function the `--gen2` flag is still required for the [2nd gen function](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/describe). Please see [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_functions_3) for more details regarding cloud functions.

To describe the 2nd gen function use below command:

```
gcloud functions describe FUNC_NAME --region=REGION --gen2
```

or

```
gcloud functions describe FUNC_NAME --gen2
```